# AMDGPU-PRO driver on loki

Tags: release-loki, graphic-drivers, amd

loki is based on ubuntu 16.04, which has some issues with amd proprietary drivers, but according to http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx, everything should work, right?

Unfortunately, I tried to install these drivers on loki-release (following installation notes, I ensured that my user belongs to 'video' group), but it ended up with black screen. I had to uninstall drivers to make my OS work again.

Kernel: 4.4.0-67-generic
Distro: loki
GPU: r7 260x

Any ideas? Should it work ootb?

Comment: I too got the blackscreen after I installed the drivers for my RX480 and had to run "amdgpu-pro-uninstall" in recovery mode to get video back.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running an RX 580 in my machine, and I would only consider the AMDGPU-PRO drivers acceptable and functional with a newer kernel. I've only tested 4.15.x, but it's the one variable that put forth positive results.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the Autoinstall command in Terminal. This should work in every ubuntu and debian distro variants

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Also try to update your Kernel and make sure that your OS is the latest.

```
sudo apt upgrade &&
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```